# Why can't I see spyder-terminal after installing plugin using pip (Windows 10)?

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Python 3.9.0 and Spyder 4.2.0 on Windows 10 (x64) machine. Via official [repo](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal), I installed the `spyder-terminal` plugin using `pip`. It installed successfully. After installation, when I open the Spyder IDE, I can't see the terminal. I tried digging into `View>Panes` and also under `Preferences`, but couldn't see any hints towards enabling/checking the spyder-terminal?

Did someone come across the same issue and has a workaround to suggest? Am I missing some dependencies?

Here is the output of `pip list`:

```
alabaster 0.7.12
appdirs 1.4.4
argon2-cffi 20.1.0
astroid 2.4.2
async-generator 1.10
atomicwrites 1.4.0
attrs 20.3.0
autopep8 1.5.4
Babel 2.9.0
backcall 0.2.0
bcrypt 3.2.0
black 20.8b1
bleach 3.2.1
certifi 2020.12.5
cffi 1.14.4
chardet 4.0.0
click 7.1.2
cloudpickle 1.6.0
colorama 0.4.4
coloredlogs 15.0
cryptography 3.3.1
cycler 0.10.0
decorator 4.4.2
defusedxml 0.6.0
diff-match-patch 20200713
docutils 0.16
entrypoints 0.3
flake8 3.8.4
helpdev 0.7.1
humanfriendly 9.1
idna 2.10
imagesize 1.2.0
intervaltree 3.1.0
ipykernel 5.3.4
ipython 7.19.0
ipython-genutils 0.2.0
ipywidgets 7.5.1
isort 5.6.4
jedi 0.17.2
Jinja2 2.11.2
joblib 0.17.0
jsonschema 3.2.0
jupyter 1.0.0
jupyter-client 6.1.7
jupyter-console 6.2.0
jupyter-core 4.7.0
jupyterlab-pygments 0.1.2
keyring 21.5.0
kiwisolver 1.3.1
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3
lxml 4.6.2
MarkupSafe 1.1.1
matplotlib 3.3.3
mccabe 0.6.1
mistune 0.8.4
mypy-extensions 0.4.3
nbclient 0.5.1
nbconvert 6.0.7
nbformat 5.0.8
nest-asyncio 1.4.3
notebook 6.1.5
numpy 1.19.4
numpydoc 1.1.0
packaging 20.4
pandas 1.1.4
pandocfilters 1.4.3
paramiko 2.7.2
parso 0.7.0
pathspec 0.8.1
pexpect 4.8.0
pickleshare 0.7.5
Pillow 8.0.1
pip 20.3.3
pipdeptree 1.0.0
pluggy 0.13.1
prometheus-client 0.9.0
prompt-toolkit 3.0.8
psutil 5.7.3
ptyprocess 0.6.0
pycodestyle 2.6.0
pycparser 2.20
pydocstyle 5.1.1
pyflakes 2.2.0
Pygments 2.7.2
pylint 2.6.0
pyls-black 0.4.6
pyls-spyder 0.3.0
PyNaCl 1.4.0
pyparsing 2.4.7
PyQt5 5.12.3
PyQt5-sip 12.8.1
PyQtWebEngine 5.12.1
pyreadline 2.1
pyrsistent 0.17.3
python-dateutil 2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server 0.4.0
python-language-server 0.36.2
pytz 2020.4
pywin32 300
pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0
pywinpty 0.5.7
pyzmq 20.0.0
QDarkStyle 2.8.1
QtAwesome 1.0.2
qtconsole 5.0.1
QtPy 1.9.0
regex 2020.11.13
requests 2.25.1
rope 0.18.0
scikit-learn 0.23.2
scipy 1.5.4
seaborn 0.11.0
Send2Trash 1.5.0
setuptools 51.0.0
six 1.15.0
snowballstemmer 2.0.0
sortedcontainers 2.3.0
Sphinx 3.3.1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp 1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp 1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp 1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath 1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp 1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4
spyder 4.2.1
spyder-kernels 1.10.1
spyder-notebook 0.3.1
spyder-terminal 0.5.0
spyder-unittest 0.4.1
terminado 0.9.1
testpath 0.4.4
textdistance 4.2.0
threadpoolctl 2.1.0
three-merge 0.1.1
toml 0.10.2
tornado 6.1
traitlets 5.0.5
typed-ast 1.4.1
typing-extensions 3.7.4.3
ujson 4.0.1
urllib3 1.26.2
watchdog 1.0.1
wcwidth 0.2.5
webencodings 0.5.1
wheel 0.35.1
widgetsnbextension 3.5.1
wrapt 1.12.1
xterm 0.7.3
yapf 0.30.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that Spyder plugins, spyder-terminal and spyder-notebook, are compatible with Python 3.7 and not Python 3.9.

Comment: What about Python 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

Click on View => Pane => IPython Console. Ipython console should open up at the bottom right corner

Comment: Thanks, Sahil for the response. I can see already see the iPython console so there is no need to toggle it on and off. I asked about the spyder-terminal which is an integrated terminal, and I can't see it anywhere in the Spyder IDE.